# A way to log the output from the Msys terminal in OSGEO4W?

Tags: gdal, osgeo, log, msys

Is there a way to log all the text output from commands in the Msys terminal to a text file when using OSGEO4W in Windows? I'm using GDAL commands and specifically wish to record any error messages that come up.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I would like to do the following with ogr2ogr commands...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still something I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 1):

This has helped me get this working:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr

Its called redirection. I have used

```
2>> filename.txt
```

to redirect the error messages to a text file.

I also found that using

```
--debug ON
```

in my ogr calls helped to give more verbose messages in the log file.